# Adding elements without separate layout file (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making a calculator UI. How can I overwrite and add some elements parameters when the screen goes to landscape mode but without making a separate layout-land file and duplicating all the elements? For example I want to change some Buttons width and height and maybe add few extra buttons but everything else stays the same

My activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.mat.calculator.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"></include>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My content_main.xml where my UI is defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mat.calculator.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infoTextViewTop"
            style="@style/textViewSpace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text=" - - - "/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button00"
            android:text="mc"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:text="m+"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button00"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:text="m-"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button30"
            android:text="mr"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button20"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:text="C"
            android:layout_below="@id/button00"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:text="\u00F7"
            android:layout_below="@id/button00"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button00"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button21"
            android:text="\u00D7"
            android:layout_below="@id/button00"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button31"
            android:text="\u232B"
            android:layout_below="@id/button00"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button20"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button02"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_below="@id/button01"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_below="@id/button01"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button00"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button22"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_below="@id/button01"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button32"
            android:text="\u2212"
            android:layout_below="@id/button01"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button20"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button03"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_below="@id/button02"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_below="@id/button02"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button00"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button23"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_below="@id/button02"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button33"
            android:text="\u002B"
            android:layout_below="@id/button02"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button20"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button04"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_below="@id/button03"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_below="@id/button03"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button00"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button24"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_below="@id/button03"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button34"
            android:text="\u003D"
            android:layout_below="@id/button03"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button20"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="32%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button05"
            android:text="\u0025"
            android:layout_below="@id/button04"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_below="@id/button04"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button00"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button25"
            android:text="."
            android:layout_below="@id/button04"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="16%" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing height/width is easy, open (or create) `values.xml` under the `values` folder, add a dimension to it like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="btn_width">20%</dimen>
</resources>
```

New create another `values.xml` in a folder called `values-land` (create the folder if needed), and put the following in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="btn_width">30%</dimen>
</resources>
```

Now in your layout xml file, use it like so:

```
android:layout_widthPercent="@dimen/btn_width"
```

Now, if you want to actually **change** the layout, as in add more buttons, what you can do is export the shared layout block (where you define the matrix of button to a new xml file "`buttons.xml`", and include it from your `content_main.xml` file.
Create a new layout xml "wrapper" file in `layout-land` folder, with the needed changes, and include `buttons.xml` in that too.

You'll be adding a new layout file to `layout-land` but they'll be sharing the same inner layout buttons file, so you won't be duplicating any buttons between the two files.